# Image comes out of UIImageView when I swipe for row action in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uitableviewrowaction

I have UIImageView in TableViewCell and that image view is positioned to the superview of that cell. I had written a function for editActionForRow to swipe and perform action but when I swipe the cell the image goes out of the UIImageView as shown below.The auto layout is also set perfectly, it doesn't have any problem but when we go for swipe it gives me a headache.If anyone could help.Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: try `clipsToBound `

Comment: It worked..Thanks @EICaptainv2.0

Comment: Please post as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Select imageview and go to attribute inspector. Checkmark the clip to bound option.